# Infinite number of rows in collection view

Tags: swift

I have a collection view where I show days of the week with days of the month and want to make it scroll to weeks, months or years later.

[image: daysCollectionView]

The following code is the point:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1000000 //number of days
}
```

When I tried the above code, I Observed a huge difference in performance when loading the controller also the memory allocation was increased by 180MB (before it was 30 cells).

How can I set the number of cell to Infinite so I can scroll the years, 
Or is there is a way to change cells count dynamically every time I step forward by week or month or year.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: When you scroll forward in time older days will no longer be shown so what you need to do is to decide how many days are visible to the user at the same time because that is your limit, not infinity.

Comment: Is your collection view wrapped in a scrollview by any chance?

Comment: @Sulthan yes its parent view is a scroll view

Comment: Vertical scroll view

Comment: @FamousMaxy So, what is the frame of your `collectionView`? Are you sure you are not actually displaying all the cells at once without any reusing? Wrapping long collection views or table views inside a scroll view is usually the cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

The Cell reuse is fit for memory allocation, while cell prefetching is not so good for memory allocation.

use `collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = false`, to balance memory allocation with user experience.

Here is [apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1771771-isprefetchingenabled), isPrefetchingEnabled

> When true, the collection view requests cells in advance of when they will be displayed, spreading the rendering over multiple layout passes. When false, the cells are requested as they are needed for display, often with multiple cells being requested in the same render loop. Setting this property to false also disables data prefetching. The default value of this property is true.